# Slow cursor movement in large Org-mode file and the `org-do-latex-and-related` function

Tags: scroll, emacs, latex, org-mode, slowdown

In an org file with almost 5000 lines,  scrolling is unbearably slow unless I turn `font-lock-mode` off. Checking what's going on in the `profiler`, that the main cause of the slowdown is the function `org-do-latex-and-related`, defined in `org.el`. It seems it's stuck in a `while` loop:

```
         - org-do-latex-and-related                             16587  54%
          - if                                                  16587  54%
           - progn                                              16587  54%
            - catch                                             16587  54%
               while                                            16587  54%
```

The goal of this function is to fontify LaTeX snippets of code within an org buffer. However, I don't have any LaTeX snippet of code in my massive org file. Does any one know how come is this function be using so many resources in an Org file with no LaTeX code?

Comment: For the record: it seems my great mistake was `(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related '(latex script entities))`. Leaving it at `nil` takes my system back to sanity and I can now happily scroll up and down my massive org-mode file with hundreds of headings, subheadings, subsubheadings, etc., and thousands of lines.

Comment: So, even though setting `org-highlight-latex-and-related` is very commonly done so that latex fragments are highlighted, it is not worth the while if it slows your system very noticeably, as was my case!

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I was struggling debugging the performance issue for large org file, and ended up looking at the safe function. Same issue with you, no latex source code in the entire org file, but it takes a huge amount of CPU to render. I ended up doing `(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related nil)` and things finally chilled.

Comment: I have to set `org-latex-and-related-regexp` to `nil` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I found this question when trying to resolve my issues with org mode hanging. And I think the answer I posted at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/60446/12751 may help here to.

Is it possible you have a really long line?

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-prevent-extremely-long-lines-making-emacs-slow

I was running org mode with executable source code via [babel][1] and one of the default [results type][2] puts all the results on one **huge** line and my emacs was unresponsive to `C-g` or `ESC` to the extent I was always killing the process.

`C-x =` (what-cursor-position) says column=386996

Emacs 27 now has `so-long-mode` included by default. Turning that one instantly showed me the problem.

You can enable that globally via `(global-so-long-mode 1)` (see [So Long docs][3]).

This will drop you out of the major mode into `so-long-mode` giving you a chance to fix the long lines before switching back to the the original mode.